# GCD Domain Proof

Tags: ring-theory, proof-writing, divisibility, unique-factorization-domains

Let $D = \mathbb{R} + X \mathbb{C}[X]$

Show that $\gcd_D(X^2,iX^2)=\emptyset $

Here is my plan so far... (and my questions)

Suppose $f \in \gcd_D(X^2,iX^2) $.

How do I show that because X is prime in $\mathbb{C}$ then $X\mid f$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$ so therefore $if \in D$.

From $fg = X^2$ and $fh = iX^2$ how can I conclude that $ig=h \in D$ and then that $if \in CD_D(X^2,iX^2)$ which will lead me to a contradiction... I believe.

If anyone can help me fill in the blanks that'd be great!

Comment: $GCD_D$ is a strange notation, that doesn't get any clearer to me as I read the problem. Isn't $X$ a divisor of both $X^2$ and $iX^2$ in $D$?

Comment: @GregMartin It is. But so is $iX$, and neither $X\mid iX$ nor $iX\mid X$ in $D$. So neither of them is a greatest common divisor.

Comment: So is $\gcd_D$ a set or an element of $D$? Your last comment makes it seem like an element, but you use $\emptyset$ and $\elem$ with it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ If the gcd $\,g$ exists then by definition $\,f\mid x^2,\,ix^2\iff f\mid g.\,$ Hence $\,x^2\nmid ix^2\,\Rightarrow\, x^2\nmid g.\,$ Also $\ x,ix\mid x^2,ix^2\Rightarrow\,x,ix\mid g,\ $ so $\ g = \ cx,\,\ c \in \Bbb C.\,$ But $\,x\mid cx\,\Rightarrow\,c\in \Bbb R,\,$ contra $\,ix\mid cx.$

Comment: Is the definition of $\gcd$ that every common divisor *divides* it, or just that every common divisor has degree less than or equal to it?

Comment: @Greg The universal definition of gcd is $\ c\mid a,b \iff c\mid\gcd(a,b).\ \ $ For $\,c = \gcd(a,b)\,$ the direction $\,(\Leftarrow)$ shows a gcd is *common* divisor, and the direction $(\Rightarrow)$ shows that it is a *greatest* common divisor (w.r.t. divisibility).

Comment: I disagree: to me, the fact (in the normal integers) that every divisor divides the greatest common divisor is a (simple) theorem, not a definition.

Comment: @Greg That definition of gcd generally works only in domains with a Euclidean algorithm, but the universal definition works in any domain (e.g. in higher-dimensional UFDs, i.e. non-PID UFDs). One can use either definition in $\,\Bbb Z.\,$

Comment: fair enough...!